# Beam Dataflow python job fails in dist_proc/dax/shuffle/batch/chunking_shuffle_writer.cc#146

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a Dataflow job that fails repeatedly with the following log message:

> 022-03-27T01:39:21.871476411ZAn exception was raised when trying to execute the workitem 1257504293434498471 : Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 646, in do_work work_executor.execute() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 210, in execute op.finish() File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 171, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.ShuffleWriteOperation.finish File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 172, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.ShuffleWriteOperation.finish File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 174, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.ShuffleWriteOperation.finish File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/shuffle.py", line 593, in **exit** self.writer.Close() File "third_party/windmill/shuffle/python/shuffle_client.pyx", line 185, in shuffle_client.PyShuffleWriter.Close OSError: Shuffle close failed: b'FAILED_PRECONDITION: Precondition check failed. [type.googleapis.com/util.MessageSetPayload='[dist_proc.dax.internal.TrailProto] { trail_point { source_file_loc { filepath: "dist_proc/dax/shuffle/batch/chunking_shuffle_writer.cc" line: 146 } } trail_point { source_file_loc { filepath: "dist_proc/dax/shuffle/batch/chunking_shuffle_writer.cc" line: 102 } } }']'

I tried running the job a few times, and it fails in the same place each time. Other than that error and the set of DoFns that were running, I don't have many clues about where to look for problems.

I suspect it's my code that causing a problem. Would love advice on how to diagnose this.

Comment: This looks like something you'd need to contact user support to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [runner v2](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#dataflow-runner-v2)?

Comment: I tried adding that, but I got the same error.

Comment: Runner V2 doesn't use dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.ShuffleWriteOperation . How were you enabling it?